# Logstash not loading config pipeline on startup

Tags: logstash, centos7, elastic-stack, systemd

I installed the ELK (version 5.6 elastic / logstash / kibana) stack on a CentOS 7 (using version 5.6) box using the rpm method, and have services enabled to run on startup. I verify it is running after reboot like so:

```
ps aux | grep logstash
logstash   744  4.6  2.2 3381144 363308 ?      SNsl 09:06   0:48 /usr/bin/java -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xmx1g -Xms256m -Xss2048k -Djffi.boot.library.path=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/jni -Xbootclasspath/a:/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar -classpath : -Djruby.home=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby -Djruby.lib=/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jruby/lib -Djruby.script=jruby -Djruby.shell=/bin/sh org.jruby.Main /usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb logstash/runner.rb --path.settings /etc/logstash
```

I don't see anything in that process command regarding my pipeline configurations. In my settings file, I have `path.config : /etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf`.

This is modified from the default `path.config : /etc/logstash/conf.d/` which according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html) does the exact same thing (and I've tried both).

The 3 files I have are valid, as I can ingest data manually using:
`/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f '/etc/logstash/conf.d/{fileA,fileB,fileC}.conf'` (or I can run them individually).

I want these ingestion pipelines to start when my server reboots, but I believe I have my configurations set correctly. I even re-ran the `system-install` script for good measure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up manually changing the `systemd` config for logstash by going to `/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service` and changing:

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
```

to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash" "-f" "/etc/logstash/conf.d/{fileA,fileB,fileC}.conf"
```

After rebooting, I discovered the process was indeed loading these pipelines.

Comment: The path actually is : `/etc/systemd/system/logstash.service`. Yes, your answer helped me. Thanks.